# How to ssh into kind cluster nodes with containerd runtime?

Tags: kubernetes, containerd, kind

I have created a Kind cluster with containerd runtime.
Here is my node:

```
root@dev-001:~# k get nodes -o wide
NAME                          STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE       KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
local-cluster-control-plane   Ready    control-plane,master   7d8h   v1.20.2   172.18.0.2    <none>        Ubuntu 20.10   5.4.0-81-generic   containerd://1.4.0-106-gce4439a8
local-cluster-worker          Ready    <none>                 7d8h   v1.20.2   172.18.0.5    <none>        Ubuntu 20.10   5.4.0-81-generic   containerd://1.4.0-106-gce4439a8
local-cluster-worker2         Ready    <none>                 7d8h   v1.20.2   172.18.0.3    <none>        Ubuntu 20.10   5.4.0-81-generic   containerd://1.4.0-106-gce4439a8
local-cluster-worker3         Ready    <none>                 7d8h   v1.20.2   172.18.0.4    <none>        Ubuntu 20.10   5.4.0-81-generic   containerd://1.4.0-106-gce4439a8
```

How I can ssh into nodes?

Kind version: 0.11.1 or greater

Runtime: containerd ( not docker )

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Nope

Comment: @deepak These answers below have enough information to solve your question. Otherwise please update your question with additional details on what went wrong, where did you stuck, errors, anything that will help to understand what doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kind Kuberenetes uses Docker to **[create container(s) which will be Kubernetes node(s)](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/)**:

> [kind](https://sigs.k8s.io/kind) is a tool for running local Kubernetes clusters using Docker container “nodes”.

So basically the layers are: your host -> containers hosted on yours host's docker which are acting as **Kubernetes nodes** -> on nodes there are container runtimes used for running pods

In order to SSH into nodes you need to exec into docker containers. Let's do it.

First, we will get list of nodes by running `kubectl get nodes -o wide`:

```
NAME                 STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE       KERNEL-VERSION    CONTAINER-RUNTIME
kind-control-plane   Ready    control-plane,master   5m5s    v1.21.1   172.18.0.2    <none>        Ubuntu 21.04   5.11.0-1017-gcp   containerd://1.5.2
kind-worker          Ready    <none>                 4m38s   v1.21.1   172.18.0.4    <none>        Ubuntu 21.04   5.11.0-1017-gcp   containerd://1.5.2
kind-worker2         Ready    <none>                 4m35s   v1.21.1   172.18.0.3    <none>        Ubuntu 21.04   5.11.0-1017-gcp   containerd://1.5.2
```

Let's suppose we want to SSH into `kind-worker` node.

Now, we will get list of docker containers (`docker ps -a`) and check if all nodes are here:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS         PORTS                       NAMES
7ee204ad5fd1   kindest/node:v1.21.1   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   10 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes                               kind-worker
434f54087e7c   kindest/node:v1.21.1   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   10 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes   127.0.0.1:35085->6443/tcp   kind-control-plane
2cb2e9465d18   kindest/node:v1.21.1   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   10 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes                               kind-worker2
```

Take a look at the `NAMES` column - here are nodes names used in Kubernetes.

Now we will use standard [`docker exec` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) to connect to the running container and connect to it's shell - `docker exec -it kind-worker sh`, then we will run `ip a` on the container to check if IP address matches the address from the `kubectl get nodes` command:

```
# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  kind  lib  lib32  lib64  libx32  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
...
11: eth0@if12: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    inet 172.18.0.4/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global eth0
    ...
#
```

As can see, we successfully connected to the node used by Kind Kubernetes - the IP address `172.18.0.4` matches the IP address from the `kubectl get nodes` command.

Comment: try with latest version of kind and runtime as contained not docker

Comment: @deepak - ["While kind uses docker or podman on your host, it uses CRI / containerd "inside" the nodes"](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/) - I am using containerd as the runtime on the nodes (check the output of the `kubectl get nodes -o wide` in my answer) On the host I am using the docker because kind supports only docker or podman - by default it is docker so I assumed  you probably you also use it.

Comment: @deepak - Check my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68933251/kind-kubernetes-cluster-doesnt-have-container-logs/68942057#68942057) for better clarification and understanding how kind Kubernetes works.

Answer (score -1):

A simple google search will reveal the answer:

https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/on-prem/1.3/how-to/ssh-cluster-node

---

#### Using SSH to connect to a user cluster node

- Get the SSH key for a user cluster:

```sh
kubectl --kubeconfig [ADMIN_CLUSTER_KUBECONFIG] get secrets \
        -n [USER_CLUSTER_NAME] ssh-keys \
        -o jsonpath='{.data.ssh\.key}' | base64 -d > \
        ~/.ssh/[USER_CLUSTER_NAME].key \
        && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/[USER_CLUSTER_NAME].key
```

where:

`[ADMIN_CLUSTER_KUBECONFIG]` is the path of your admin cluster's kubeconfig file.

`[USER_CLUSTER_NAME]` is the name of your user cluster.

---

#### The preceding command performs the following steps:

- From the admin cluster, get the `ssh.key` field of a Secret named ssh-keys in the [USER_CLUSTER_NAME] namespace.
- Base64 decodes the key.
- Store the decoded key in the file ~/.ssh/[USER_CLUSTER_NAME].key.
- Set appropriate access permissions for the key file.

#### Use the key to SSH into a user cluster node:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/[USER_CLUSTER_NAME].key user@[NODE_IP]
```

where:

- `[NODE_IP]` is the internal IP address of a node in your user cluster, which you gathered previously.

Comment: Not using gke/anthos cluster, we are having kind (https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) local cluster with containerd runtime.
```
NAME                          STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE       KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
local-cluster-control-plane   Ready    control-plane,master   7d8h   v1.20.2   172.18.0.2    <none>        Ubuntu 20.10   5.4.0-81-generic   containerd://1.4.0-106-gce4439a8
```